# Django: Internet explorer download page content instead of rendering it

Tags: python, html, django, internet-explorer

I am creating a website using Django Web Framework.
When I view it with browsers like chrome, safari, firefox, etc it work properly, but if I open the page in Internet Explorer this happens:

[image]

In my views.py I have this code:

```
def index(request):

    context = RequestContext(request)

    c_form = False
    try:
        c_form = request.COOKIES['cform']
    except Exception:
    if request.POST: c_form = foo_email(request)

    context_list = {'form': c_form}
    response = render(request, 'base_home.html', context_list, context)
    if c_form: response.set_cookie('cform', value='1', max_age=None)
    return response
```

The response variable contains the HTML structure of the page, other browsers render it but, IE doesn't, why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing invalid arguments to `render()`. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), it takes the following arguments:

> ```
> render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None)
> ```

You are passing `context` to the `content_type` argument, which somehow doesn't break altogether, but ends up in the response not containing a `text/html` content type. Hence IE tries to download it.

Remove that last argument:

```
response = render(request, 'base_home.html', context_list)
```